# In Joomla 3.2 for Unite Revolution Slider, the first slide is coming , then others are not coming. Only taking the space for slide

Tags: jquery, css, joomla

I installed the Unite Revolution Slider on Joomla 3.2 administrator part. Then Assigned the Unite Revolution Slider Module to a specific postion i mentioned in template's templateDetails.xml. But on the front end, the sliders are not coming properly . All the sliders are coming from very top of the page, not coming at the exact position i mentioned. Not only this, only the 1st slide's image is being placed at proper postion after coming to top. But all the other slide's images are becoming hidden after coming from top once.

Here i am attaching that how the slide is coming. On the top the slider image is coming, Under that the exact position, where it should come, but not coming:

Comment: Have you tried contact the developer of the extension? Can yuou provide a link to the site? Have you tried debugging the issue with your browser developer tools?

Comment: I cleared cache several times before refreshing page. And no js error is coming here

Comment: " Error in parsing value for opacity " is coming as css error

Comment: And I will ask again >> Have you tried to contact the developer of the extension? Can yuou provide a link to the site?